# Question about classifying groups of order $20$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I am reading the solution [here](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_algebraist_2004&task=show_msg&msg=1066.0001): http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_algebraist_2004&task=show_msg&msg=1066.0001

> Assume G non-abelian. Case 2) all $4$-sylow subgroups of $G$ are cyclic. Take any element $b$ in $G$ of order $4$. Then since $<g>$ is normal in $G$, $bgb^{-1} = g^i$ for some $i$. $i \neq 1$ since $G$ is nonabelian. $i$ is not $0$ either (clearly!). if $i = 2$ then $b^3gb^{-3} = g^3$. If $i = 3$ then $bgb^{-1} = g^3$. Either case you get an element $b$ of order $4$ such that $bgb^{-1} = g^3$. So $G$ is generated by $a,b$ subject to $|a| = 5$, $|b| = 4$, $bgb^{-1} = g^3$. In the case $bgb^{-1} = g^4$ you get a different group.

So in the case of $i=4$, we have $bgb^{-1} = g^4$, so we have $b^3gb^{-3} = g^4 \neq g^3$, so for the case $i = 4$, it's different from $i = 2$ and $i = 3$, but $i = 2$ and $i = 3$ are the same. But if we use $b^2gb^{-2}$ instead of $b^3gb^{-3}$, then we get that for $i = 2$ that $b^2gb^{-2} = g^4$, and for $i = 3$ that $b^2gb^{-2} = g^4$, so it would imply that $i = 2$ and $i = 3$ are all the same as $i = 4$. Why isn't this true? Why do we specifically only care about the $b^3gb^{-3}$ case, and not about $b^2gb^{-2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subgroup generated by $b$ is acting on the subgroup generated by $g$ via conjugation (this works because $\langle g\rangle$ is normal in $G$). The reason why the $i = 2$ and $i = 3$ case are "the same" is because $b \mapsto b^3$ is an automorphism of $\langle b\rangle$, whereas $b \mapsto b^2$ is not ($b^2 = (b^3)^2$, but $b \neq b^3$). The automorphism $g \mapsto g^3$ of $\langle g\rangle$ induced by conjugation by $b$ or $b^3 = b^{-1}$ has order $4$ (it is an *isomorphism* of $\langle b\rangle$ with $\text{Aut}(\langle g\rangle)$, the automorphism $g \mapsto g^4$ induced by conjugation by $b$ only has order $2$, and represents a mere *homomorphism* of $\langle b\rangle$ into $\text{Aut}(\langle g\rangle)$.

Thus we have two *distinct* semi-direct products $\langle g\rangle \rtimes \langle b\rangle$, the first two (the $i = 2,3$ cases) are isomorphic.

In the $i = 4$ case, we have:

$b^2gb^{-2} = b(bgb^{-1})b^{-1} = bg^4b^{-1} = (bgb^{-1})^4 = (g^4)^4 = g^{16} = g$ (since $|g| = 5$).

Conjugation by $b^2$ is not equivalent to conjugation by $b$.

Comment: Is there an easy way to check whether a function is an automorphism or not, without checking the homomorphism and bijective properties? Like to realize that $b \mapsto b^2$ is not an automorphism, I would have to check that it's a homomorphism, surjective, and injective until I find that it's not injective (as you showed). Like some properties of the group involved or something?

Comment: Not...always. In this case, things are simplified enormously by the fact that  $b$ is of order $4$. Now a cyclic group of order $4$ is abelian, so $b \mapsto b^n$ is going to be a homomorphism no matter what. But it is only going to be an isomorphism if $\gcd(n,4) = 1$, and since $4$ is such a small number, it's easy to check all possible cases: only $1$ and $3$ as choices for $n$ yield an isomorphism (an automorphism of $C_4$).

Comment: No. the elements of the domain are the elements $\{e,b,b^2,b^3\}$, for each one of these we get an isomorphism of $\langle g\rangle$ with itself: for example, if $bab^{-1} = g^4$, then $b$ maps to the homomorphism that sends $g^k \mapsto bg^kb^{-1} = (bgb^{-1})^k = g^{4k}$. As I showed above, $e$ and $b^2$ both yield the same mapping, the identity on the group generated by $g$.

Comment: But $b^2$ yields the mapping $g^4 \mapsto g$, which is not the identity mapping. Because we have $bab^{-1} = g^4$, then $b^2$ maps to the homomorphism that sends $g^4 \mapsto g^{(4)(4)} = g$. And $g^4 \mapsto g$ is not the identity mapping

Comment: $b^2$ maps to conjugation by $b^2$, not conjugation by $b$. Look, suppose we define $\phi: \langle b\rangle \to \text{Aut}(\langle g\rangle)$ by: $\phi(b) = h_b$, where $h_b(g) = bgb^{-1} = g^4$. Then $b^2$ maps to $h_b\circ h_b$, which sends $g$ to $h_b(h_b(g)) = (g^4)^4 = g$.